# Applying reverse QgsCoordinateTransform on QgsGeometry in PyQGIS

Tags: coordinate-system, pyqgis, point, coordinates

I have defined `xform` as a `QgsCoordinateTransform` to project geographic coordinates.

I can use:

```py
unprojPoint = xform.transform(point, QgsCoordinateTransform.ReverseTransform)
```

to do the reverse operation, but how can I apply this to a `QgsGeometry`?

I can do:

```py
line.transform(xform)
```

alright, but this won't take a direction argument.
I would expect something along the lines of:

```py
line.transform(xform, QgsCoordinateTransform.ReverseTransform)
```

would work but no luck...

Do I have to set up a new `QgsCoordinateTransform` to do this?

*Note:* I am using QGIS 3.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this if you dig into the low-level [`QgsAbstractGeometry`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsAbstractGeometry.html) API. Try:

```py
line_data = line.constGet().clone()

try:
    line_data.transform(xform, QgsCoordinateTransform.ReverseTransform)
except:
    # catch transform errors!
    pass

transformed_line = QgsGeometry(line_data)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I hadn't got deep enough obviously! Still, it feels like a miss that you can't apply a direction directly onto a QgsGeometry.

Comment: Sure does, thanks for raising this! Will be fixed by https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/6774